# Update Hidden Field Value Inside PHP Function

Tags: php

I am new to php and am trying to update a hidden field value inside a php function and can't see to find a solution that works.

In template.php I have:

```
<input type="hidden" id="variable_ID" name="variable_name" value="variable_value">
```

This works fine.

However I need to update the value of the variable to the record ID of inserted record in a function in functions.php eg

```
function myFunction() {

$insert_record = $mydb->query("INSERT INTO `Table`(`Name`) VALUES ('John')");
$get_record_id = $mydb->insert_id;

// *** Set Hidden field value to $get_record_id here ***

}
```

I have tried a myriad of things but can't seem to find a solution.
Any pointers on how to solve this problem?

Comment: You can only update html fields after page load via direct insertion (e.g. a user types in something or other "native" input) or via javascript. ........ Sounds like you need *before* page load. You could perhaps show more code?

Comment: Would this happen on form submission or some other event?

Comment: EL_Vanja... the function in functions.php is called from an Ajax function in script.js after a button click.

Comment: You can't set it with PHP. Your PHP function needs to return the value and then you can set it in your AJAX success handler.

Comment: GetSet... How would you update it using javascript? I tried a few methods but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: El_Vanja... how would I do this? I have tried a few different ways however the variable doesn't seem to assign in the success handler.

Comment: El_Vanja... Thanks for your pointer. I got there in the end.

Answer (score 1):

## Additional answer

You're correct AJAX is an asynchronous construct which means that certain tasks can be carried out *before* you might expect them to (from a synchronous perspective).

For example we can (as per the code in the original answer) use jQuery to update the value of a field directly in the success handler.

We can't update a JS variable directly, i.e:

```
some_variable = response.value;
```

If you attempt it the variable `some_variable` will likely be `undefined`.

The difference comes down to `callbacks`:

> Callbacks allow the asynchronous function to call a function *after* it completes. Where as setting a variable happens *on the spot*.

There are two *easy* ways to solve this issue then:

1. Create a function outside of the AJAX request and allow it to *callback* that function once the AJAX request has completed -- as you've already discovered.
2. Use the `complete` option inside of your AJAX request.

### Using a call back

Firstly we need to define out variable to be updated and the function which we will use to update it:

```
var inserted_id = "";
function update_id(data){
    inserted_id = data.record_id;
}
```

Then we can make out AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    type    : "POST",
    url     : "/url/to/functions.php",
    data    : {data:"to be posted"},
    dataType: 'json',
    success : update_id         
});
```

N.B.
Calling `update_id` in this fashion means we pass the entirety of the returned JSON object; not just the returned number.

Alternatively...

```
var inserted_id = "";
function update_id(data){
    inserted_id = data;
}

$.ajax({
    type    : "POST",
    url     : "/url/to/functions.php",
    data    : {data:"to be posted"},
    dataType: 'json',
    success : function(response){
        update_id(response.record_id);
    }
});
```

This method is effectively the same but we only pass the returned number to the `update_id` function.

### Using complete

`complete` works the same way as `success` however activates once the AJAX request is... complete...

```
var inserted_id = "";
$.ajax({
    type    : "POST",
    url     : "/url/to/functions.php",
    data    : {data:"to be posted"},
    dataType: 'json',
    complete: function(data) {
        inserted_id = data.responseJSON.record_id;
    }
});
```

---

---

## Original answer

Having not seen the rest of your code giving a complete answer is tricky. However, this should set you on the right track:

### PHP

Firstly, in your `PHP` you need to make sure and output the data that you want returned to the webpage. In this case we want to return the `insert id` of the newly created record; to do this we're going to output a `JSON` object so that the `AJAX` call can interpret the value and update the page:

```
function myFunction() {
    $mydb->query("INSERT INTO `Table`(`Name`) VALUES ('John')");
    echo json_encode(["record_id" => $mydb->insert_id]);
    exit;
}
```

**N.B.**

- We don't want  any output other than the `JSON` string. Hence `exit` has been used after the echo. You may want/need to adjust the `echo` and `exit` to fit with the rest of your code etc.

### JS

Now that we have our `PHP` returning usable data to our ajax call (which should look something like the below) we can take the returned data aka `response` and update the value of the hidden field accordingly.

```
$.ajax({
    type    : "POST",
    url     : "/url/to/functions.php",
    data    : {data:"to be posted"},
    dataType: 'json',
    success : function(response) {
        $("#id_of_hidden_field").val(response.record_id);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Steven. Thanks for this - and the clear explanation. However I am now getting the following error.  jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:4 POST http://localhost:8888/terencesweeney.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)
send @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:4
ajax @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:4
(anonymous) @ script.js?ver=5.5.3:47
dispatch @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:3
r.handle @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:3

Comment: Here is the actual Ajax function with your new code if it helps any...    jQuery.ajax({
      url: ajax_url,
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        action: "createSurveyInstance",  // calling the "createSurveyInstance" in functions.php file to create a new survey instance
        user_email: user_email,
        user_f_name: user_f_name,
        getsurveyTypeid: getsurveyTypeid,

      },
      processData: false,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (response) {
         $("#survey_Instance_ID").val(response.record_id);
      }
    });

Comment: @TerenceSweeney Okay, that usually means there's a problem with the data being submitted... Firstly try adding `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` as an option to your `AJAX`. If that doesn't work wrap your `data` object with `JSON.stringify()` like `JSON.stringify({action: "create.....}`. If that doesn't work add an `error` handler as an ajax option `error: function (error) { console.log(error);}`

Comment: Hi Steven. Thanks for your direction. I got there, in the end, using your answer for direction. I want to post the solution I used - but the solution now doesn't fit with the question. If I change the title and text of the question your answer will probably need changing. Otherwise, I could always post as a new question and answer myself with the solution but then you won't get deserved credit. What is the etiquette regarding this?

Comment: @TerenceSweeney glad to hear you managed to get your code working! You're more than welcome to do either of things you suggested (i.e. post a new question/change this one and answer yourself). Without knowing what you had to do to get it working it's hard to judge **best practice:**  if _this answer solved this question_ and then you had to do something else then you can _accept this answer_ and ask another question. If on the other hand _this answer_ wasn't complete then you can _add your own_ - there's always upvotes to show appreciation. Tbh I'm intrigued to know what solved it fo you.

Comment: Okay thanks. I have posted the solution I used here.

Comment: @TerenceSweeney Excellent, I'll take a look!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I used - thanks to @Steven and @El_Vanja for direction.

(I may need to change the question title now though because what I actually needed to do was return a variable to javascript from PHP using Ajax. I didn't need to use hidden fields).

**PHP**

```
function myFunction() {

$insert_record = $mydb->query("INSERT INTO `Table`(`Name`) VALUES ('John')");
$get_record_id = $mydb->insert_id;

echo json_encode($get_record_id);

exit;
}
```

**JS**

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: ajax_url,
  type:'POST',
  data: {
    action: "myFunction",
    anydata:"to be posted"},
    
  success: process_record_ID
});
    
function process_record_ID(data_returned_from_myFunction){
  recordID = data_returned_from_myFunction;
}
```

Hope this helps others!

Notes

1. I believe that we have to declare 'process_record_ID' as a separate function outside of AJAX because AJAX is asynchronous. If we define the function in the success handler, the function runs in AJAX before the value is actually returned from PHP.
2. In the AJAX success handler, we don't need to explicitly list the 'data_returned_from_myFunction' variable in the call to process_record_ID function. When the data is returned to the AJAX success handler from PHP, it still gets sent to the function.

Comment: Good to see that you got it working! The difference is that if you place the function in the `success` handler it can't be used as a _callback_ by jQuery where as if you define it outside of the ajax call then it can. You should note that calling the function the way you have results in the entire returned object being passed on, not just the number/value (I've added some explanations to my original answer to further explain this -- which may or may not be of interest to you)

Comment: Okay. Thanks for clarifying.